# jQuery function calling twice, once from our own js and next from jquery.min.js

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi, I am using jQuery in my application and for swiping event I used jquery mobile, due to usage of both in one application I had an issue that is the swiping event gets fired twice, one time from my own js file and second time the code copied into jquery.min.js, and executing from there.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var wrap = $('.slides_wrap');
    var slides = wrap.find('.img_slide');
    slides.on('swipeleft', function(e) {
        console.log('called swipeleft');
        $('a.carousel-control .rightArrow').click();
    });
    slides.on('swiperight', function(e) {
        console.log('called swiperight');
        $('a.carousel-control .leftArrow').click();
    });
  });
```

Comment: Why did you copy code into `jquery.min.js`? You should probably stay away from files like that unless you really have to ?

Comment: I don't think he's copied his code into jquery.min.js, I think he means he downloaded jQuery into that file, which is normal.

Comment: My guess is it has to do with the handler for the `click` events on the carousel controls.

Comment: i didnt copy the code but event fired once from my own js file and second time fired from jquery.min.js, i seen this in fire bug

Comment: in the same js i have another click event that is working fine. If i include jquery.mobile.js its also fired twice and this is not the issue with carousel-control.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
slides.parent().off("swiperight").on(...).click();
```

or:

```
slides.parent().off("click").on(...).click();
```

I think you have bind multiple events in closest elements. If this not work, try with .children() too.

Comment: That works for me... with jQuery v2.0.0. So, if your version is older than 1.7,try with newer version.

Comment: Thank you George Georgiev its working fine if use jquery 2.0.0 but i cannot use jquery 2.0.0 in my application